# How to point to an Image source after compiler changes the file name?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, parceljs

I want to load images from some folder (assets\png\slidingImage\SlidingImage_3.png) and then on click or after X seconds, it should go to the next image. I tried to change ...SlidingImage""""_3"""".p... this part into """"_4"""" and change images one after the other. The problem is Parcel renames images to SlidingImage_3.SOME_NUMBERS.png and these numbers are unique for every image.
Q1: How do I point to an image after Pacrel "compiles" them (if that's the term)?
Q2: How do I set Img src only with typescript without going through, How is that done in big projects?

```
    #changeImage() {
        let oldURL: string = this.#slidingImage?.getAttribute(`src`) as string;

        const newURL = oldURL?.replace(`_${this.#oldActiveDot?.getAttribute('data-dot')}`, `_${this.#activeDot?.getAttribute('data-dot')}`);

        this.#slidingImage?.setAttribute('src', oldURL);

    }
```

This does the job of replaceing the number in the URL based on which dot is active, but those random numbers are added without my consent :S.

[image]
o
This is logged image URL.

Q3: Is there a way to point to a 1st or specific file in some folder (even after the compiler munches them together? To find a file based on something in the name?

Thanks in advance, random helper!

Comment: Well, I didn't know until now, but yes. Is it possible to do that and are there any other ways to refer to the image name with hash before it gets compiled and get's that unique hash?

Comment: What you sent me is exactly that, but I get an error "bundles must have unique name." so I cant find a way to add that.

Comment: Thank You. I managed to find a workaround. I added class to all images and just looped throw them (adding and removing the "hidden" class). Not the best solution for bigger examples of this I assume, so I'm still on a hunt for a better soliton :>.

Comment: I do believe you might need a webpack's `require.context()`.